# "Relatively" functionally complete connectives

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The Sheffer stroke (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) is *functionally complete*: any truth-functional connective (such as $\wedge, \vee, \rightarrow$, . . .) can be represented purely in terms of the stroke.

My question is about a version of the Sheffer stroke for a certain subclass of formulas:

Say that a (propositional) sentence $\varphi$ is **essentially positive** if it is satisfied by the assignment making every propositional variable "true." It is a good exercise to show that all such sentences can be expressed using only the connectives "$\wedge$" and "$\implies$"; see e.g. [A formula $\phi$ is logically equivalent to a another formula which contains only propositional variables and the connectives $\wedge$ and $\to$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523327/a-formula-phi-is-logically-equivalent-to-a-another-formula-which-contains-onl). Moreover, any sentence expressible just using "$\wedge$" and "$\implies$" is essentially positive.

My question is: can we make do with a *single* connective? Specifically:

> Is there a single truth-functional such that the sentences expressible using that functional as a connective are exactly the essentially positive formulas?

It's pretty easy to see that there isn't such an operation which is *binary*, just by enumerating the possibilities, but there isn't an obvious reason why the simplest such functional couldn't be 15-ary, say.

More generally,

> Suppose I have a finite collection of truth-functional connectives $\{C_i: i\in I\}$. When is there a single truth-functional connective $C$ such that the sentences expressible using $C$ are exactly those expressible using $\{C_i: i\in I\}$?

Comment: Re your first question, this ternary connective should do the trick: $$\triangleleft(A,B,C) := (A\Rightarrow(B\land C)).$$ In terms of this, we can define $A\Rightarrow B := \triangleleft(A,A,B)$ and then $A\land B := \triangleleft(A\Rightarrow A,A,B)$. Clearly, $\triangleleft$ and $\Rightarrow, \land$ are inter-expressible, so the sentences that each set generates are the same, i.e. the essentially positive ones. // I have to think more about the more general case.

Comment: @BrianO Nice, I did not think it would be that simple!

Comment: @BrianO: although it is not so hard in retrospect, that would make a reasonable answer to the question

Comment: @CarlMummert OK I'll take you up on that, *merci*. It's a reasonable half-answer, anyway.

Comment: Re the general question, for infinite $I$, perhaps there are two cases to consider: (1) the set of sentences $S$ expressible using the $C_i$ can be finitely generated, i.e. for *some* finite set of connectives $\{C'_j\mid j\in J\}$, not necessarily among the $C_i$, $S$ is the sentences expressible using the $C'_j$, and (2) $S$ is not finitely generated. In case (2), of course there's no such connective $C$; showing that the case isn't vacuous may just be a cardinality argument. I'm considering the question in between other things, so.. take what I just said with a brick of salt.

Comment: @BrianO I think we can restrict attention to finite $I$: suppose $\Delta$ is a relatively complete connective. Then $\Delta$ can be expressed in terms of finitely many of the $C_i$s, so that finite subfamily already generates all of $\{C_i: i\in I\}$.

Comment: Yep. A cardinality argument does show that not all sets of sentences are "finitely generated" in the sense above. So, back in $V_{\omega}$ again.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Terminological question: is there a source for "positive" or "essentially positive" in your sense? I was [told](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1248989/5191) that $\land$ and $\to$ are more usually considered to be _negative_...

Comment: @ZhenLin Nope, that was just me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question has a simple answer — this ternary connective does the trick:
$$\triangleright(A,B,C):=(A\Rightarrow(B\land C)).$$

In terms of this connective, we can define 
$$A\Rightarrow B:=\triangleright(A,A,B)$$
and then 
$$A\land B:=\triangleright(A\Rightarrow A,A,B). $$

Clearly, $\{\triangleright\}$ and $\{\Rightarrow,\land\}$ are inter-expressible, so the (truth functions corresponding to the) sentences that each set generates are the same, i.e. the essentially positive ones.